# How to turn off reasoning in the Grakn python client

Tags: reasoning, vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am using the Grakn python client and I want to query for data without reasoning turned on.

```
client = GraknClient(uri=uri)
session = client.session(keyspace=keyspace)
tx = session.transaction().read()
```

Do I pass an argument in the `transaction()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the reasoning off for every specific query by passing `infer=False` parameter like this

```
transaction.execute(query, infer=True, explain=False, batch_size=50);
```

Check out the documentation http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python#lazily-execute-a-graql-query